# Gas Flow Rate and Pressure Difference

Tags: pressure, flow, air

I have a pipe with two ends and on each end the pressure of the air is different. Is there any relation that can tell me the flow rate/speed of air inside the pipe because of the difference in pressures at the two ends of the pipe ?

Is there any equation that can relate the pressure difference at two end with the speed of the air inside the pipe? What pressure difference will cause how much speed of air inside the pipe ?

Comment: In the simplest case, this is just Bernoulli's equation, isn't it? Of course, there are plenty of more elaborated model. E.g. you can include that friction on the walls, or include turbulences.

Comment: so Bernoulli's equation can determine what i have asked ? @semoi

Comment: Well, that depends on your assumptions. If you assume an ideal gas and thus no friction between the walls and the particles, Bernoulli is your friend. Maybe you could tell us why you think Bernoulli that is not appropriate. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_principle

Comment: and what if the case is not ideal and there is friction ?

Comment: Then things get more complicated and you have to define it in detail, before any answer can be posted. For example I would expect that the velocity depends on the diameter and it's length.